# Enable / Disable firebase listeners

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listeners

In my firebase app I would like to be able to enable/disable the real time connection. Can this be done? I reviewed the documentation and have not found anything that relates to my use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database's [`goOffline`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goOffline) and [`goOnline`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goOnline) methods might be what you are looking for.